# Print out array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I have an integer and an integer that I get from a hashmap stored in an array called finalAns.

```
int[] finalAns = {};
finalAns = new int[]{1, 3};
System.out.println(finalAns);
```

When I print it out I get **[I@77459877**

How do I get [1,3] when I print out the final answer (`System.out.println(finalAns)`)?

Comment: By the way, most of that code is irrelevant. You could just have said you have an array `int[] finalAns = new int[]{1, 3};`. Please read about [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `Arrays.toString(array)`. What you see here is the default `toString()` representation of arrays, or Objects in particular.